# More elegant way of adding a percentage?

Tags: php, math

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of adding a percentage. For example, if I wanted to add 12% of `$a`'s value to `$a` I'm doing:

```
$a = 100;
$a = $a + (($a / 100) * 12);
```

Which gives me `112` as the new value, of course. But I can't help but feel this is a little too verbose and there must be a better way of doing the percentage addition.

I tried:

```
$a = $a + 12%;
```

But, as expected this doesn't work. Before I consider writing a function myself to make this easier, is there a pre-existing way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not `$a *= 1.12;`?

"Percent" comes from latin "per centum", or "per hundred".  One percent is 1/100.  So twelve percent is 0.12 - twelve hundredths.

Comment: if you simplify your equation, you'll find just that one

Comment: I didn't know about the `*=` operator to be honest. But... I did know about percentages ;) Thanks for the answer, though. Will set as answer in 8 mins, when the site lets me.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is:

```
$a *= 1.12;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how I do it:

```
$percent = 10;
$price *= (1 + $percent / 100);
```